# Laravel 4 extending Pagination Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to extend laravel 4's pagination class to add my own methods to it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can just extend Laravel Paginator Class :

```
class YourPaginator extends Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
```

You also have to create a new service provider if you want your custom pagination class to replace Laravel one (See [Pagination Service Provider](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/PaginationServiceProvider.php)) and replace current pagination provider with yours on app config file.